# AppDelegate: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ---

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, key-value-coding

In `AppDelegate.h` I created the following property,

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *googleUserDetailsDictionary;`

In `AppDelegate.m`,

`static NSString *kGoogleDetails = @"googleDetails";
@synthesize googleUserDetailsDictionary;`

I've made a custom method in `AppDelegate.m` in which I added the following line:
`[self setValue:googleUserDetailsDictionary forKey:kGoogleDetails];`

In the ViewController which I wanted to be a observer for `googleUserDetailsDictionary` property,

`AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"googleUserDetailsDictionary" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:kGoogleDetails]) {
        NSLog(@"This is change taking place: %@ \t\t", change);

    }
}
```

Then I get the following Error JUST WHEN I TRY TO OPEN THE `ViewController`: 
`** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRA_AppDelegate-1470253453284 0x7fd4fa839410> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key googleDetails.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's telling you the truth.  You don't have any property called `googleDetails`.

Try changing the key path to match the property, such as:

```
static NSString *kGoogleDetails = @"googleUserDetailsDictionary";
```

Comment: That worked! :)

But I've a doubt. I've read that only sub-classes of NSObject are internally complied to `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol whereas for other classes, we should manually set it. But I actually didn't do that for UIAppDelegate but still it worked! How?

Comment: Also if you care answering this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758112/understanding-the-concept-ensuring-kvc-compliance

Comment: When you're working in Objective-C, most classes are NSObject sub-classes.  (Check your class declaration in AppDelegate.h.)  It becomes more of a concern in Swift.